# Android Source Code Compilation issue

Tags: android, c++, compiler-errors, android-camera, android-source

i am working on one of C++ Application, where i need to interface with Android Source Code, i got this Source Code from below URL

> https://github.com/android

Now When i am Compiling my application which uses Camera module, then it has many dependencies like **utils,binder,gui,system**. by this way i am including every header files which camera module of Android depends depends on.

but i am stuck with following error:

```
In file included from jni/headers/camera/ICamera.h:22:0,
             from jni/headers/MyCamera.h:4,
             from jni/headers/VideoWrapper.h:4,
             from jni/src/com_example_jnitest_VideoJava.cpp:2
jni/headers/binder/Parcel.h:31:7: error: template argument
required for 'class Flattenable'
class Flattenable;
   ^
jni/headers/binder/Parcel.h:105:37: error: invalid use of 

template-name 'android::Flattenable' without an argument list
 status_t            write(const Flattenable& val);
                                 ^
jni/headers/binder/Parcel.h:160:30: error: 'Flattenable' is not a type
 status_t            read(F
```

**my Question is**:How to get out of this error??

Comment: What's unclear with the error message?

Comment: i am not clear what it does mean @ChristianHackl

Comment: oh.. i wonder how this can be issue with Android Code?? error: template argument
required for 'class Flattenable' is solved by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850809/error-template-argument-required-for-struct-list

Comment: @ChristianHackl unclear thing is do need to change in android source code? or i need to check work around before changing.. this way i am stucked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever Any class Template need to be pre-declaration in another class or Anywhere then we need to give it with template

e.g:
in Parcel.h file of Android source, pre-declaration of class Flattenable is done as below:

```
class Flattenable;
```

but actually it should be:

```
template <typename T> class Flattenable;
```

because class Flattenable is Template class.
**However i Amazed how this things not taken care into Android Source Code..!!**